# Why does passing an actual array (not an array variable) as an argument to a function throw an error?

Tags: c++

So, I was trying to learn pointers from scratch and I hit up on this.
I tried doing the following:

```
void func(int* ptr){
  //Yada-yada
}
int main(){
  int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  func(a);
}
```

which worked out great. But then, I tried to do the following:

```
void func(int* ptr){
  //Yada-yada
}
int main(){
  int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  func({1,32});
}
```

which returned an error saying

> too many initializer values
> So I replaced it with

```
func({1});
```

which ended up with

> a value of type "int" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "int *"

So I'd like to know why this happens. Does the compiler not allocate space for an array that is not being used as an rvalue for a variable?? Because if it does, the expected result would be that `ptr` is passed the address of the first variable in either of the {1,32} or {1} cases.

Thanks in advance.
P.S : Only reply to this if you intend to help. If you have comments to tell me to go read a book or something, I already am. But to the ones who actually want to be helpful, links to references are very much appreciated.

Comment: `{1,32}` is a `std::initialized_list<int>`, which is not convertible to an `int *`.

Comment: read about [std::initializer_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)

Comment: `{1,32}` is not an array. It doesn't have a type at all according to the C++ language specification. It's a syntactic construct that can be used to initialize objects. Sometimes, the properties of the object can be deduced from it, but those are the exceptions, not the rule.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica you should post as answer.

Answer (score 5):

`{1,32}` is not "an actual array". It is a brace enclosed list of initialisers. The pointer parameter cannot be initialised with such list unless the list contains exactly one initaliser of a type that is convertible to the pointer.

Comment: So, the 2nd case fails because a initializer list with multiple items is not compatible in general. The 3rd case fails instead because the list with 1 item would be compatible if the contained `int` would be compatible but it isn't. (The OP was lucky that the last snippet contained [`{ 1 }` but not `{ 0 }`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d0437b0b21bade1) which had caused even more confusion.)